# Can someone identify this bird? It looks like it has a few deformities

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image: the featherless neck of a bird, turned 90 degrees]
[image: the malformed wings of a bird with no feathers on its neck, turned 90 degrees]

All pictures taken at Lake Roberta in Tampa, FL.
All pictures depict the same bird.

(The wing deformities can be explained by the lake water being slightly highly toxic, but the neck I can only assume to be caused by the Muscovy ducks that live in the lake.)

Comment: What does "*slightly highly toxic*" mean? Just a little bit highly toxic? Sort of toxic? Mildly polluted?

Comment: How can ducks make it have an odd neck? What's odd about it?

Answer (score 15):

It's an anhinga, as@kmm commented. There's nothing wrong with it; it's not deformed in any visible (to me) way. They spread their wings to dry, as they are darting birds that [do not float on the surface of the water, but beneath it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anhinga).

Here's one drying itself on a turtle.

[image]